# Seleccionar un solo valor de una relación muchos a muchos

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Tengo un problema a la hora de obtener los registros de una BD a través de una relación muchos a muchos, tengo las siguientes tablas:
[image: Tablas Postgres]

Al momento de extraer los datos del cpu, existen cpu's que tienen varias tarjetas de red, por lo que tengo una relación muchos a muchos, el problema es que no se como obtener los las tarjetas de red sin que se repita el cpu.

La consulta que realizo es la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT cpu.id_cpu, nic.mac, nic.dir_ip FROM cpu 
JOIN activo_fijo ON cpu.id_activo = activo_fijo.id_activo 
JOIN nic_cpu ON nic_cpu.id_cpu = cpu.id_cpu 
JOIN nic ON nic.id_nic = nic_cpu.id_nic;
```

La consulta me devuelve lo siguiente:
[image: Salida sql]

Como ven el registro con id_cpu: 39 se repite ya que ese cpu tiene 2 tarjetas de red.

Lo que quisiera obtener son esos datos en un solo registro, o en todo caso omitir una tarjeta de red, ya que tengo que listar todos los cpu's existentes y en este caso se repetirían algunos, ya que hay varios cpus con dos tarjetas de red;

Esto es lo que quiero evitar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Existe alguna manera de hacerlo en SQL o en PHP?.**

Estoy usando **PHP** como lenguaje de programacíon y **postgresql** como BD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Lo que quisiera obtener son esos datos en un solo registro

Puedes utilizar la función [**`string_agg`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) para concatenar `mac` y `dir_ip`. Es decir:

```sql
  SELECT cpu.id_cpu,
         string_agg(nic.mac, ', '),
         string_agg(nic.dir_ip, ', ')
    FROM cpu
    JOIN activo_fijo ON cpu.id_activo = activo_fijo.id_activo
    JOIN nic_cpu ON nic_cpu.id_cpu = cpu.id_cpu
    JOIN nic ON nic.id_nic = nic_cpu.id_nic
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Gracias esto funcionó perfectamente.

Answer (score 3):

Quizás buscas esto:

```sql
SELECT
  x.id_cpu, x.mac, x.dir_ip
FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id_cpu ORDER BY t.mac) AS r,
    t.id_cpu, t.mac, t.dir_ip
  FROM
    (SELECT nic_cpu.id_cpu, nic.mac, nic.dir_ip FROM cpu
     JOIN nic_cpu ON nic_cpu.id_cpu = cpu.id_cpu
     JOIN nic ON nic.id_nic = nic_cpu.id_nic) t) x
WHERE
  x.r = 1;
```

Comment: Gracias ya lo probé, es muy buena alternativa.

Comment: La ventaja de esta opción es que te puede dar todas las columnas de la fila de mac para una mac

Answer (score 1):

Que hay de usar [DISTINCT](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/)

```sql
Select DISTINCT id_cpu, mac, dir_ip from (
  SELECT cpu.id_cpu, nic.mac, nic.dir_ip FROM cpu 
  JOIN activo_fijo ON cpu.id_activo = activo_fijo.id_activo 
  JOIN nic_cpu ON nic_cpu.id_cpu = cpu.id_cpu 
  JOIN nic ON nic.id_nic = nic_cpu.id_nic
)
```

---

O Usando un Left join

```sql
SELECT cpu.id_cpu, nic.mac, nic.dir_ip FROM cpu 
LEFT JOIN activo_fijo ON cpu.id_activo = activo_fijo.id_activo 
LEFT JOIN nic_cpu ON nic_cpu.id_cpu = cpu.id_cpu 
LEFT JOIN nic ON nic.id_nic = nic_cpu.id_nic;
```

---

Op 3: Group by

```sql
SELECT cpu.id_cpu, max(nic.mac), max(nic.dir_ip) FROM cpu 
JOIN activo_fijo ON cpu.id_activo = activo_fijo.id_activo 
JOIN nic_cpu ON nic_cpu.id_cpu = cpu.id_cpu 
JOIN nic ON nic.id_nic = nic_cpu.id_nic
group by id_cpu
```

Comment: Si lo hice pero sigue devolviendo el mismo resultado.

Comment: Y si lo cambias asi?

Comment: Lo pruebo y te comento los resultados.

Comment: Ya lo probé, pero obtengo el mismo resultado.

Comment: Ok dejame pensar, puedes cargar el sql de las tablas a sqlfiddle por ejemplo, para no mandatte cosas a ciegas

Comment: Gracias la Op 3 funcionó.